# SSL Self-signed Expired Certificate in Java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore

Hi I am accessing a developmental API that only has a self signed, expired certificate through Java, and unexpectedly I am getting the error about unable to find valid certification path to requested target. so I went to the url with firefox and exported the certificate to add to my keystore, using `keytool -importcert -alias mycert -file mycert.cert -keystore cacert`, thinking that it should work now. But upon making the call, I am still getting the same error.

Am I missing some step to link up the cert to java?

the error is

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
>       ... 22 more

UPDATE: problem solved. location of keystore was wrong.
should be {location of java home}/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: Consider that your `cacert` will be wiped when you update your JRE.

Comment: It belongs in your TrustStore.

Answer (score 0):

> exported the certificate to add to my keystore

No you didn't, you added it to your *truststore*. You shouldn't modify the one in the JRE, for the reason GregS gave, you should create your own and tell the server to use it.